# Expo SDK 44 upgrade error - "expo-cli upgrade"

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to upgrade expo to the latest version - SDK 47 from SDK 44 that I am currently using.
My npm version is 8.19.2, node version is 16.18.2 if it helps.

When I tried running the command: expo-cli upgrade, I am getting the following error:

```
✖ Failed to install expo package with error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
    at NpmPackageManager.installAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:82:16)
    at NpmPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:96:18)
    at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:109:5)
    at upgradeAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
    at actionAsync (/Users/abcd/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)
```

After reading a bit on the internet, I tried deleting the "package.lock.json" file but I have no idea why it would have worked as it didn't.

I also checked "babel-preset-expo", which is set to 9.0.2 as it should be as per another article.

It will be great if anyone here could help me with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with node v16.4.0 while upgrading from SDK 44. Changing to v14.17.6 or v19.1.0 made the "expo upgrade" command work properly. These are examples, I am sure it works with other versions, just test by yourself.
You can find node versions on this link : https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json

If you do not want to change your node version for some reason, I do not have a solution for it then. I am currently in this case and searching for a solution ...